# Open Api Generator 7.2 using kotlin-server generator, does not respect useJakartaEe config

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, openapi-generator

I have a Quarkus (3.6) Gradle (7.6) Kotlin (1.9.22) Project
Quarkus uses Jakarta since Quarkus 3.x
Open Api Generator added support for the kotlin-server generator to use JakartaEE instead of javax in version 7.0.0, see PR: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/15593/files

I am fighting with this issue, just can't get it to work...

my task looks like this:

```
task<org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask>("generateAdapterServerApi")
{
    generatorName.set("kotlin-server")
    inputSpec.set("$rootDir/../spec/adapter.yaml")
    outputDir.set("$rootDir")
    modelNameSuffix.set("Dto")
    library.set("jaxrs-spec")
    packageName.set("example.adapter")
    configOptions.putAll(
        mapOf(
            "useJakartaEe" to "true",
            "interfaceOnly" to "true",
            "sourceFolder" to "src/gen/kotlin"
        )
    )
}
```

Is there any way to make it work?

i tried it with different generators, but it seems only this kotlin-server generator officially supports what I need... But seems it is not working